# Describe anonymous VBA Object

Tags: vba, pdf, acrobat

I'm using a badly documented library ("Acrobat Acrobat 10.0") to modify PDF documents using VBA.

In order to perform this modification, I use an Object (JavaScript Object), which represents a VBA interface to a JavaScript library. My problem: I can't find any documentation online. I can find the corresponding [JavaScript documentation](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf), but nothing that describes what I need/in a way that I need it.

Is it possible to iterate over the methods/properties of an 'anonymous' object?

Comment: Unfortunately VBA doesn't support introspection the way java does.

Comment: This example is pretty straighforward... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIAC_DevApp_OLE_Support%2FCreating_a_simple_application.htm&rhsearch=debugger%20reader&rhsyns=%20

Comment: @Amorpeuses - thanks the the confirmation :).

Comment: @joelgeraci - yes, I'm aware of this documentation, but can't find any reference to what I'm trying to achieve - I need to enable javascript execution in the pdf document.

Comment: Neither VBA or VBA plus some JavaScript can be used to enable JavaScript in Acrobat. That's a user preference but JavaScript is on by default. However, if the JSO object returns null, then you know JavaScript has been disabled. Also, the JSO is pretty dumb. Acrobat will try to run whatever you send it, think of it as the equivalent of JavaScript "eval". What exactly are you trying to do in the document?

Comment: @joelgeraci I populate the fields in a javascript document (accessing the fields through the JSO). This document has some built-in javascript functionality, which isn't executed properly when I populate it programatically.

Comment: ah... ok... is it possible that you are trying to populate a calculated field? If so, the value you send through the JSO will get overriden. How about a date field with the wrong pattern? In that case, the field will not populate. Can you share the form?

Answer (score 1):

If you can early-bind (Tools -> References...) the library, then you can already use the *Object Browser* (F2) to browse its modules and all the members it exposes, and read every member's *docstring* if it exists.

If you can't early-bind the library and can only work with `Object`, you're pretty much stuck: the only way to iterate members of a library is to load that library; VBA doesn't have native support for *reflection*, but with [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s experimental COM API you can definitely do that... as long as the library is referenced.

Comment: I initially tried this, but it's not possible to early-bind the JSO object. I had the feeling this was this the case, thanks for the confirmation :).